# how to rotate 2 div to form an x?

Tags: html, css

I need to rotate 2 div to form an x, I have this:

```css
.line-rotate-top {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.line-bottom {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="line line-rotate-top">
  <span class="line-top kopp"></span>
</span>

<span class="line line-bottom">
  <span class="line-top kop"></span>
</span>
```

An X is formed but they are displaced only intersect at the top

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS was incomplete and it doesn't show anything out, I fixed it. You need to specify the `transform-origin` and adjust the margin:

```css
.line {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
}

.line-rotate-top {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.line-bottom {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<span class="line line-rotate-top">
  <span class="line-top kopp"></span>
</span>

<span class="line line-bottom">
  <span class="line-top kop"></span>
</span>
```

This is what you get:

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses `absolute` positioning for each `span`. This means that the spans need to be placed in the parent container with relative positioning - `.cross_box`. Basically, it's enough to just add the color and dimensions of your lines.

And yet, I slightly changed the html structure of your spans.

```css
.cross_box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.line-top{
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  width: 30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.line-bottom{   
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  width: 30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);   
}
```

```html
<div class="cross_box">
  <span class="line-top">
  </span>
  <span class="line-bottom">
  </span>
<div>
```

Comment: No explanation of what needs to be done? Oh you completely changed the original code.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, now I have given a description. Yes, I decided to change the structure of html in my own way.

Comment: Cool man, thanks. It looks decent. 

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, thank you very much. Your solution is great too :)

Comment: Thanks man, I just pointed out where exactly the OP is wrong and gave a solution. And obviously, in decent code terms, your answer is the good one.